# Is there an open standard for the CAFR (Comprehensive Annual Finance Report)?

Tags: government, finance, standards

I would like to push my local government to provide the Comprehensive Annual Financial Report ([CAFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_annual_financial_report)) as an open data source.  I was wondering if we could go one step further by providing it in a particular open standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be a *separate* data standard for CAFR, but you may want to consider [XBRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL) (eXtensible Business Reporting Language).

The [State of Oregon piloted providing CAFR in XBRL format](http://www.wikixbrl.info/index.php?title=CAFR) and there are [some tools that exist to help provide XBLR formats of a CARF](https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/cafr-parsing).

Answer (score 3):

Two standards you may wish to consider are XBRL and Frictionless Data.

I have been working on a municipal XBRL taxonomy with others.  You can see the current status here:  https://github.com/govwiki/us_municipal_cafr_taxonomy

For more on the application of Frictionless Data to fiscal reporting see: https://frictionlessdata.io/specs/fiscal-data-package/

Comment: XBRL US has now released a demonstration CAFR taxonomy.  Please see: https://xbrl.us/xbrl-taxonomy/2019-cafr/